# Magento 2.1.3: Overriding of vendor layout file with my custom layout file in Magento 2.1.3 is not working?

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, magento-2.1.3

I have created a custom module in Magento 2.1.3 and its layout file is located in

> app/code/RP/Testmodule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

but the system loads the layout from

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

instead of my custom layout file.

How can I override this vendor layout file with my custom layout file?

My customer_account_create.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">RP_Testmodule::form/register.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but the module does not take this layout.

I have created the resister.phtml and it is located in

> app/code/RP/Testmodule/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

My register.phtml file is

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

My module.xml file is

> app/code/RP/Testmodule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="RP_Testmodule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

My di.xml file is

> app/code/RP/Testmodule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
</config>
```

My registration.php file is

> app/code/RP/Testmodule/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'RP_Testmodule',
    __DIR__
);
```

These commands are executed successfully

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

But all after that, still it's not working.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">RP_Testmodule::form/register.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

This is working for me.

Comment: Negative, still it's not working.

Comment: have you flushed cache after update it?

Comment: Flush, clean, di:compile all tried

Comment: Is there another  modules who overriding same file?

Comment: No, it's a fresh Magento setup

Comment: Ok, manually remove `var/cache/*` folders and try it with my code

Comment: No, still negative

Comment: hope module enabled ;)

Comment: It's active. In module:status - showing in enabled list.

Comment: can you share your module with zip/tar?

Comment: Yes, here the link [RP.zip](https://files.fm/u/faau4gkn)

Comment: Oh! crap. Sorry, that was my mistake. The module name was wrong in one file. Thank you very much for your co-operation.

Comment: module name was not wrong in `RP_Testmodule` module, right?

Comment: @KunalRay, If my answer and comment solves/help your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: I've tried for upvote but as I've <15 reputations that's why it's not granting. In registration.php that was `RP_TestModule`. BTW, thank you again. :)

Comment: Welcome, it is ok, I can understand, happy to help you.

Comment: I think it is correct `<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
 'RP_Testmodule',
 __DIR__
);
`

Comment: The file which I gave you, there was some modification. Actually, I haven't noticed for the registration.php file but after some time I've noticed & realized that this may be the issue.

Comment: Ahh, ok, Great finally got solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change to your template with:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" template="Vendor_Modulename::filename.phtml"/>
```

Comment: It's also not working.